Correct way to 'clone' git repository with a local config
For headless build agents, I would like to clone a git repository with a local config.
The reason for this is that auth should be solved with an injected token in a custom credential manager.
I know I could have used global or system level config, but I am not a fan of mixing configs with all the other build jobs (and occasional terminal sessions).
To get a local config, I basically:

Create and cd into the directory
git init -b {branch}
git config --local credential...
git remote add origin {url}
git pull origin {branch}
#if submodules
git submodule update --init --recursive
#endif

If the job needs to tag and push the branch, I need to do a 'git push --set-upstream origin  {branch}', but at this stage, I would rather not have to specify the branch (this whole scenario is packaged in a reusable component).
How can I 'prepare' the local git directory, as it would have been, had I used 'git clone {url} -b {branch}' ?


git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/{branch} {branch}


I've tried that, but it will fail if nothing has changed.

What does it mean "nothing has changed."? git pull doesn't fetch a branch? I tested these commands on a real repo. First I did git clone to see .git/config. Then I ran all commands; git pull origin fetched a branch, I changed nothing in it and immediately ran git branch --set-upstream. Looking into the second .git/config I see it was configured in exactly the same way as after git clone. What's your problem? Was something fetched with git pull? What was the error message? What is the list of remote branches? git branch -r?

@phd sorry, my bad, I put git branch before git pull, then it complained with 'fatal: no commit on branch {branch} yet'. If you add your comment as an answer, I can select it as the chosen solution.

Check that 5. git pull origin {branch} fetched the branch and add this command after 5 or 6:
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/{branch} {branch}

